# Sass - selecting a header with specific role but not apply styling if has certain class

Tags: html, css, sass

## Question

How to nest the SCSS to apply styles to a `<header>` only if it has a `role="banner"` but it must not apply if the header has a class of `page-frontpage`. Then I will nest the style for the specific page inside.

### Background

I am adding onto someone elses code, so not allowed to overwrite the first style written. I think there could be a problem if a header is used somewhere else, so i want to target the styles if it has a role of "banner". I am writing the style for the homepage, and my page has a different layout, so I want the previous styles to not be applied to my page.

I understand this is not the best way to do it, but I have to work within this scope.

### Code

Here is [my demo on codepen](http://codepen.io/JGallardo/pen/pEKXOo)

#### HTML

The class is passed into the header based on what page is being viewed

```
<header role="banner" class="<?=$varCurrentPage?>">
```

### SCSS

Original code

```
header{
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #444;
    color: #fff;
    min-height:80vh;
    background-size:cover;
    position:relative;
}
```

So far modified

```
header[role=banner] {
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go:

```
header[role="banner"]:not(.page-frontpage) {
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #444;
    color: #fff;
    min-height:10vh;
    background-size:cover;
    border: red 1px dotted;
    position:relative;
}
```

Comment: OK so the part I am stuck on is if it is best ("cleaner") to nest the styles for the `.page-frontpage` inside there somehow or if I should just write the styles under that as `header[role="banner"] { &.page-frontpage { } }`

Comment: If I am right, you want to have certain styles for header[role="banner"] and then some additional styles for same element that is not on front page?

Comment: In that case you can just nest :not(.page-frontpage) via adding & to the front:`&:not(.page-frontpage)`. But I don't think nesting is especially clean thing to do. After all, the css output is the same.

Comment: I agree. I ended up just limiting their styles like shown above. Then wrote another set of rules. Works fine now. I appreciate the help, thank you.